# Merging multiple ohlc csv with overlaps into one sorted csv file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I'm trying to merge multiple OHLC csv files into one file. I downloaded some data on the internet-web but with indexes partly overlapping. Data might look like:

```
<file1>
o,h,l,c,v,t
...
364.4,364.4,364.4,364.4,155.0,2019-01-01 10:59:59
364.4,364.59,364.4,364.59,371.0,2019-01-01 11:00:00
364.59,364.59,364.59,364.59,305.0,2019-01-01 11:00:01

<file2>
o,h,l,c,v,t
364.4,364.59,364.4,364.59,1371.0,2019-01-01 11:00:00
364.59,364.59,364.59,364.59,305.0,2019-01-01 11:00:01
364.59,364.59,364.59,364.59,305.0,2019-01-01 11:00:02
364.59,364.59,364.59,364.59,305.0,2019-01-01 11:00:03
...

<file3>
o,h,l,c,v,t
364.4,364.4,364.4,364.4,155.0,2019-01-01 12:00:00
364.4,364.59,364.4,364.59,1371.0,2019-01-01 12:00:01
...
```

What I need...

```
<file_merged>
o,h,l,c,v,t
...
364.4,364.4,364.4,364.4,155.0,2019-01-01 10:59:59
364.4,364.59,364.4,364.59,371.0,2019-01-01 11:00:00
364.59,364.59,364.59,364.59,305.0,2019-01-01 11:00:01
364.59,364.59,364.59,364.59,305.0,2019-01-01 11:00:02
364.59,364.59,364.59,364.59,305.0,2019-01-01 11:00:03
...
364.4,364.4,364.4,364.4,155.0,2019-01-01 12:00:00
364.4,364.59,364.4,364.59,1371.0,2019-01-01 12:00:01
...
```

I have found a neat way to load the data into one object but I'm missing the last part where I need to merge the unordered list into one ordered dataframe, where doubles are removed and data is sorted. pd.merge(left, right, index='t') I think I could use in an ugly loop but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way? This is how I loaded data so far (without the ugly loop):

```
datadir = r'/home/test'
files = [i for i in os.listdir(datadir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(datadir, i)) and i.startswith('AAPL_')]
datalist = [pd.read_csv(datadir + '/' + filename, index_col='t') for filename in files]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pathlib.Path.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) to get paths of all the files that start with `AAPL_` in `datadir` and use `pd.read_csv` along with optional parameter `parse_dates` and `index_col`, finally use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concat all the `dfs` and use [`DataFrame.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) to sort the dataframe on `index`.

```
from pathlib import Path

dfs = [pd.read_csv(p, parse_dates=['t'])
       for p in Path(datadir).glob(r'AAPL_*')]
df = pd.concat(dfs).drop_duplicates('t').set_index('t').sort_index()
```

Result:

```
print(df)
                          o       h       l       c       v
t                                                          
2019-01-01 10:59:59  364.40  364.40  364.40  364.40   155.0
2019-01-01 11:00:00  364.40  364.59  364.40  364.59  1371.0
2019-01-01 11:00:01  364.59  364.59  364.59  364.59   305.0
2019-01-01 11:00:02  364.59  364.59  364.59  364.59   305.0
2019-01-01 11:00:03  364.59  364.59  364.59  364.59   305.0
2019-01-01 12:00:00  364.40  364.40  364.40  364.40   155.0
2019-01-01 12:00:01  364.40  364.59  364.40  364.59  1371.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Looks good at first sight. Still have to do a data check.

Comment: @GrJP Sure. Happy coding!

Comment: Still trying to remove duplicate indexes. Tried using .drop_duplicates(), but then my totals in the end don't match. In my result, I'm short approx 40 lines in about 90.000 lines. Still investigating...

Comment: You are trying to drop duplicate entries with same time, right?

Comment: Yes indeed, so when a duplicate index (t column) is found, only one occurrence should be kept.

Comment: > Thanks a lot. The edit does the trick. The result is perfectly in line with what I expect. Have a nice day!